# Why does this simple Python OGR code create an empty polygon?

Tags: python, ogr, polygon-creation

Please excuse my ignorance...I am new to Python OGR.

I am trying to create a simple square polygon and fail...this produces an empty polygon.

Where did I go wrong?

```
from osgeo import ogr
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')
datasource = driver.CreateDataSource('c:/temp/testPolygon.shp')
layer = datasource.CreateLayer('layerName',geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)

#create ring and polygon object:
myRing = ogr.Geometry(type=ogr.wkbLinearRing)
myRing.AddPoint(0.0, 0.0)
myRing.AddPoint(0.0, 10.0)
myRing.AddPoint(10.0, 10.0)
myRing.AddPoint(0.0, 10.0)
myRing.AddPoint(0.0, 0.0)#close ring
myPoly = ogr.Geometry(type=ogr.wkbPolygon)
myPoly.AddGeometry
#this produces myPoly.GetArea() of zero!

#create feature polygon:
feature = ogr.Feature( layer.GetLayerDefn() )
feature.SetGeometry(myPoly)
layer.CreateFeature(feature)
```

Even the following returns an area of zero:
    from osgeo import ogr

```
#create polygon object:
myRing = ogr.Geometry(type=ogr.wkbLinearRing)
myRing.AddPoint(0.0, 0.0)#LowerLeft
myRing.AddPoint(0.0, 10.0)#UpperLeft
myRing.AddPoint(10.0, 10.0)#UpperRight
myRing.AddPoint(10.0, 0.0)#Lower Right
myRing.AddPoint(0.0, 0.0)#close ring
myPoly = ogr.Geometry(type=ogr.wkbPolygon)
myPoly.AddGeometry
print (myPoly.GetArea() ) #returns zero, not 100...
```

Comment: Do you have spaces `myRing _ .AddPoint`?

Answer (score 2):

Thanks...I forgot to specify what geometry (myRing) to pass to myPoly
myPoly.AddGeometry(myRing)

The following now works as a simple start:

```
#create simple square polygon shapefile:
from osgeo import ogr
driver = ogr.GetDriverByName('ESRI Shapefile')

datasource = driver.CreateDataSource('c:/temp/testPolygon.shp')
layer = datasource.CreateLayer('layerName',geom_type=ogr.wkbPolygon)

#create polygon object:
myRing = ogr.Geometry(type=ogr.wkbLinearRing)
myRing.AddPoint(0.0, 0.0)#LowerLeft
myRing.AddPoint(0.0, 10.0)#UpperLeft
myRing.AddPoint(10.0, 10.0)#UpperRight
myRing.AddPoint(10.0, 0.0)#Lower Right
myRing.AddPoint(0.0, 0.0)#close ring
myPoly = ogr.Geometry(type=ogr.wkbPolygon)
myPoly.AddGeometry(myRing)
print ('Polygon area =',myPoly.GetArea() )#returns correct area of 100.0

#create feature object with point geometry type from layer object:
feature = ogr.Feature( layer.GetLayerDefn() )
feature.SetGeometry(myPoly)
layer.CreateFeature(feature)

#flush memory
feature.Destroy()
datasource.Destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the fourth point be (10.0,0.0) rather than (0.0,10.0) -- which is your second point?

Comment: Yes, but i still have the problem with even simpler code:    #myPoly.GetArea() returns area of zero...
from osgeo import ogr

#create polygon object:
myRing = ogr.Geometry(type=ogr.wkbLinearRing)
myRing .AddPoint(0.0, 0.0)#LowerLeft
myRing .AddPoint(0.0, 10.0)#UpperLeft
myRing .AddPoint(10.0, 10.0)#UpperRight
myRing .AddPoint(10.0, 0.0)#Lower Right
myRing .AddPoint(0.0, 0.0)#close ring
myPoly = ogr.Geometry(type=ogr.wkbPolygon)
myPoly.AddGeometry
print (myPoly.GetArea() )